# Validation based on visibility of a label

Tags: asp.net, validation, button, label

I like to add a validation on a label based on its visibility, in that a submit button will raise a validation message or error if the label is not visible.

I am used to the validation controls in the Toolbox, which wont allow this functionality!

Comment: I assume you mean an asp:Button? Also, have you tried anything? It'd be nice if we had some attempted code.

Comment: am using a detailsview as an input form, on of the fields,if a button(not the actual submit button) is clicked then a label becomes visible(which has databound values). But I cant use validation control(am a newbie!) on a label Visibility, thus I dont know how to go about it....wud really appreciate ur input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though if an asp:Label's visibility is set to false, the asp.net engine will not even put it in the DOM. So you can check in javascript, using the `onclick` property of the (html) button to check if the label is in the DOM or not, and use asp.net's `__doPostBack()` javascript function to post back to the server if it is there:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function testMe()
        {
          var lbl = document.getElementById('lblTest');
          if(lbl == null)
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Error";
          else
            __doPostBack('testButton');
        }
      </script>
      <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Hello"></asp:Label>
      <button onclick="testMe();">test</button>
```

To be completely honest, I thought the `lbl` would be `undefined` if the label did not exist in the DOM, but Firebug revealed it is actually `null`. Anyway, a couple things to note is that in order for asp.net to define the `__doPostBack()` method, I believe you need some control in the form that has `autopostback="true"`, and in the code-behind you can check what caused the postback in the `Page_Load` method like so:

```
if(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "testButton") {}
```